# My If statement for the approval workflow is not working in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: designer

I've built this workflow and it won't execute.

If Current Item:Approval Status equals 0#Approved
   Copy item in Current Item to Corrective Action Log

The workflow completes without copying the item over.  If I leave the If statement off and just use the Copy Item function it works.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you log `Current Item:Approval Status`? Is it a dropdown? I suspect you don't need the 0#